# Zoom out of multiple strips in a grid layout

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to make a video sequence where you zoom out of one video strip to many in a grid like layout. The problem is that If I want to use scale, each video strip gets scaled from its center. If I use meta strip all other strips outside the render regions gets cropped. I also tried using adjustment layer or a new scene with adding previous one, but the problem is the same - all strips outside the region get cropped.

Comment: At this point it is probably just simpler to create a 3D scene with a plane using multiple video as textures, than fight the video editor.

Answer (score 0):

As Duarte wrote in the comments, just import your movies as planes, change the start frame as you need it, then animate your camera like this:

[image]